# Получение значений для создания массива

Tags: массивы, html

Привет. Как сделать так:
Сначала есть форма с кнопкой, где вводится размерность массива. И по нажатию создается форма (как бы таблица NxN, где N - полученное ранее значение). И с помощью этой формы получить значения и заполнить ими массив.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Алгоритм, как я его вижу, следующий:

1. Создаем форму с элементами input[type=text] и button.
2. При клике на button javascript проверяет содержимое input. Есть ли нельзя привести к числу, то `throw new Error(...)` или `alert('wrong ...')`. if (isCanBeNumdeber) dimension = parseInt(isCanBeNumdeber);
3. if (all_good) создаем новую форму и в ней таблицу с dimension рядов и dimension столбцов. В каждой ячейке по input[type=text] (на каждый input уникальный id). Также форма содержит input[type=submit]
4. При клике на input[type=submit] javascript читает содержимое всех ячеек и решает что с ними делать (или тупо отправляем на сервер, а там пусть что хотят то и делают))) ).

Comment: Собственно, мне всех больше интересно было, как таблицу с переменными размерами создать, синтаксис.
"таблицу с dimension рядов и dimension столбцов" - вот это как?

Comment: Либо [jquery][1]

[1]: https://www.google.com.ua/search?site=&source=hp&q=jquery+%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C+%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82&oq=jquery+%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7&gs_l=hp.3.0.0l10.741.3061.0.4200.7.6.0.1.1.0.118.596.4j2.6.0....0...1c.1.44.hp..0.7.606.iNwUgjRqJOE

Comment: , либо [native][2].

[2]: https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=javascript+%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0+dom&oq=javascript+%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D1%8D&gs_l=serp.3.3.0l2j0i22i30l4.48443.54921.0.57920.11.10.0.1.1.0.132.1008.7j3.10.0....0...1c.1.44.serp..0.11.1013.xQqgGHuqubU

Comment: Никаких примеров в интернете не нашел 8(

Comment: Вот вам пример. Разберитесь с тем, что я тут сделал, и все пойдет как маслу. 
   
    var form = document.createElement('form');
    var inp = document.createElement('input');
    inp.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    form.appendChild(inp);
    document.body.appendChild(form);

Comment: А как в строчку добавить, а не каждая форму друг под другом

Comment: Это уже css